# Interpretation of A/B Test with 3 Variants

Tags: ab-test

We are currently having an interresting discusison about a recent A/B Test we ran and i'd very much appreciate your thoughts on it:

We recently ran a A/B/C Test regarding the pricing of same day delivery:

- Control, current state:: free same day delivery
- Variation 1: 3 Dollars for same day delivery
- Variation 2: 5 Dollars for same day delivery

We measured:

- CR_Checkout: Overall Conversion Rate in the Checkout (including other delivery options) as:
  '# users in checkout / # transactions
- CR_SameDay: Usage Rate same day delivery as:
  '# transactions with same day option / # transactions

Results compared to Control:

- Variation 1:
- Change in CR_Checkout_1: Not Significant
- Change in CR_SameDay:_1 Significant decrease
- Variation 2:
- Change in CR_Checkout_2: Significant decrease
- Change in CR_Sameday_2: Significant decrease

Question:
Under the given circumstances - is it statistically sound to go on and make a profit calculation to compare Variation 1 and Variation 2, using the respective conversion rates, average order value (generic for both variants) and revenue from same day delivery fee - even if we have not proven a statistically significant difference between Variation 1 and Variation 2?

Example:
Variation 1:
100 Users in Checkout x CR_Checkout_1 x Average Order Value + Revenue SameDayFee = 100
Variation 2:
100 Users in Checkout x CR_Checkout_2 x Average Order Value + Revenue SameDayFee = 105
Therefore Variation 2 should be implemented.

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE, what is your _original_ hypothesis before you set up this test?

Comment: What is preventing you from tossing out the "control" results and performing your statistical tests between variation 1 vs variation 2?